# Using replace and pathArray[0], I seem to be adding rather than replacing with my JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have made a simple browser extension and have a manifest.json file that runs through a background.js file into my JavaScript file, which has this code

```html
var l=location;
var str2='/edit';

var pathArray = l.pathname.split('/');
var secondLevelLocation = pathArray[1];

pathArray[1] = 'node';

l.href=l.origin.replace(l.origin, pathArray[1])+l.pathname.concat(str2);
```

But rather than replacing pathArray[1], it's adding to the url.

For example, the script is taking: https://mywebiste.com/items/1234; 
and replacing with: https://mywebiste.com/items/node/items/1234/edit

However, the intended output is: https://mywebiste.com/node/1234/edit

### Updated

Following comments on incorrect array number, I've updated my script but naturally it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach:

```js
// emulating window.location
var l = {
  "href": "https://mywebiste.com/items/1234"
};

console.log("Input:", l.href);
console.log("Output:", l.href.replace(/items/i, "node") + "/edit");
```

Comment: But my intention is to change pathArray[0] to a different string, 'node'. It seems your reply leaves pathArray[0] as 'items' and just concats str2, correct?

Comment: @user1533064 Apologies, I misunderstood. That code should be working now, please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: ah yes, thanks Christian, it is pathArray[1] I want to replace. But updating my code from [0] to [1] has no effect, it's still adding 'node' in the url rather than replacing 'items' with 'node'.

Comment: Are you just wanting to replace a string (like `items` -> `node`) and then add `/edit` to the end? You can do that in one line: `l.href.replace("items", "node") + "/edit"`. If that works, let me know and I'll edit this answer.

Comment: I edited the snippet, @user1533064 - you can use a string, i.e. `.replace("items", ...)` instead of regex, but just in case you get a dirname like `Items`, the case-insensitive regex will catch that.

Comment: I see, I had over complicated it a bit, thank you Christian this works perfectly now

Comment: Awesome, thanks @user1533064, please mark as the answer if you wouldn't mind =)

Answer (score 1):

So, if you have your url like this: `https://mywebiste.com/items/1234` and you split it by `/`, then you will have something like this: `["https:", "", "mywebiste.com", "items", "1234"]`

as you see, the 3rd position is the `items` that you need, so you can do:

`yourUrl.replace(yourUrl.split('/')[3], 'node').concat('/edit');`

Feel free to use 'node' and '/edit' as variables as you did.

Hope it helps you.

**EDIT:**

The easiest way I can think:

`let href = location.origin + location.pathname.replace('items', 'node').concat('/edit')`

Comment: but I am splitting pathname so not including origin, but taking your point and putting it in the browser console: var pathArray = location.pathname.split('/');
console.log("Original pathArray:", pathArray);, 

I can see that as Christian says above, it's [1] I need to replace. But replacing [0] to [1] still adding /items/node/items/1234; I still can't replace items with node.

Comment: I think you are complicating things.
if you just create a variable lets say
`var href = location.origin + location.pathname.replace('items', 'node').concat('/edit')`

This is working just fine if you put it in a console. Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks Richard, I had over complicated as you say, and this works perfectly now

var l=location;
l.href=l.origin + l.pathname.replace('items', 'node').concat('/edit');